# dlopen/LoadLibrary on same application

Tags: c++, c, loadlibrary, dlopen

I need to call an exported symbol from my own application - therefore I need to know if it's safe to call `dlopen` / `LoadLibrary` on "yourself".

An example would be:

```
LoadLibrary("test.exe");
```

inside a program called `test.exe`.

I tested it and it seems to work, but I'm not quite sure if it is actually supported behavior.

Comment: why don't you call it directly if it's in your own application?

Comment: It's in a plugin architecture. Implementations (kinda like in COM) are loaded based on a mechanism from DLLs/SOs. This mechanism works with filenames. Now we have come across the usecase to define some plugins (at least as backup) inside the application. Therefor we need to expand the Loader. If we can safely load from the application via dlopen/LoadLibrary we can handle all cases in a uniform manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)...

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling **LoadLibrary** increments the reference count. Calling the **FreeLibrary** or **FreeLibraryAndExitThread** function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

It will work, just remember to clean-up after yourself by calling [FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx), as stated above.

What you may have *really* wanted instead is [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. The module must have been loaded by the calling process.

In fact, what you're trying to do is even a special case.

> *lpModuleName* [in, optional]
>
> *...*
>
> If this parameter is NULL, **GetModuleHandle** returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).

So, trying this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void print(void) {
  puts("OK");
}

main() {
  HMODULE mod = GetModuleHandle(0);
  FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress(mod, "print");
  proc();
  return 0;
}
```

... appears to work:

```
C:\dev\scrap>gcc -oprint print.c

C:\dev\scrap>print
OK
```

For [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), it appears very similar.

> If *filename* is a NULL pointer, then the returned handle is for the main program. When given to **dlsym**(), this handle causes a search for a symbol in the main program, followed by all shared libraries loaded at program startup, and then all shared libraries loaded by **dlopen**() with the flag **RTLD_GLOBAL**.

Comment: I knew about GetModuleHandle, but there is the problem of uniform handling. Currently the mapping is stored in a std::map<std::string, std::string> which maps a type to a dll/so. Therefor NULL is not an available option and a special treatment should be avoided if possible...

Answer (score 2):

A quick test on Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) FARPROC Test() { 
    printf("It worked");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    HMODULE m = LoadLibrary(argv[0]);
    FARPROC test = GetProcAddress(m, "Test");
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

produced the following output:

```
It worked
```

I suppose in theory that doesn't guarantee that it might not break on some other version of Windows, but I consider that rather doubtful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this trivially with `dlopen()` - there's a pseudo handle given as a GNU extension, `RTLD_DEFAULT` which acts like a handle to yourself, so you can simply skip the `dlopen()` call and write:

```
dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "entry_func");
```

For example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

void print(void) {
  puts("OK");
}

int main() {
  void (*proc)(void) = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "print");
  assert(proc);
  proc();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that you'll need to compile with `-rdynamic` for this to work.

According to the manpage on a recent Solaris machine `RTLD_DEFAULT` is available there too.

Comment: According to the man pages one can use dlopen(nullptr); For whatever reason RTLD_DEFAULT didn't work for me. As I'm now using GetModuleHandle on Windows, I might aswell use dlopen(nullptr) on Linux... [as I already need to handle the host program differently...]